# Modern interpreter code in c++?

Tags: c++, parsing, interpreter, lexer

I'm looking for simple interpreter code written in c++. Ideally, it would be for something no more complex than an expression evaluator with variable assignment (for the memory management code).

My reasoning is that I am working through Modern Compiler Design with the goal of being able to contribute to interpreted language engines like the V8 javascript engine. However, all of that book's code is written in C so far, and I would like to see the design practices implemented for C++ in this context, especially the memory management models but also the structure of the lexer/parser/etc in general.

I'm aware there isn't much code written that is this basic, and that C++ isn't the traditionally favored language to write interpreters (especially in the open source world), but I'm hoping someone has worked on this before and could at least point me to their personal Git repository.

I've been looking for this sort of code for about a week, but the only code I can find is far too complex to be grokked by me at this stage.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/tiny-js/

Comment: Take a look at [AngelCode](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/)

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/tinyscheme/

Comment: I've looked at AngelCode and tiny-js so far, they both seem to be fairly simple projects, especially tiny-js, which specifically uses a recursive decent parser, which is the stage I'm at in Modern Compiler Design. I'll be looking at tinyscheme later tonight, but it sounds like a likely candidate as well (bonus to both tiny-js and tinyscheme for being implementations of languages with a JS-like syntax). Post either comment as an answer and you have my vote :)

Answer (score 2):

## The C++ Programming Langauge

> I'm looking for simple interpreter code written in c++. Ideally, it would be for something no more complex than an expression evaluator with variable assignment (for the memory management code).

Have you read [The C++ Programming Langauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language)?

At chapter 6 it has nice example of simple [recursive descent parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser). And yes, it is expression evaluator with variable assignment.

Comment: I haven't, I had mostly dismissed it to be honest because it was published so long ago, I used C++ Primer Plus 6th Ed. to learn the language. I'll definitely have to look at that book though, especially since I see an updated version covering c++11, etc is due to be released in May of this year.

Answer (score 1):

[LLVM Kaleidoscope](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/) tutorial features many of the basics you'll need: decently idiomatic C++-ish lexing and parsing, intermediate representation handling, etc.

Alternatively, if you're seeking a real hardcore C++ experience, you may want to take a look at [Boost::Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/), there is a wealth of examples ranging from simple expression evaluators to complex grammars.

Comment: I'll be looking at the LLVM link, I've been reading about it (being one of the main VM/JIT/compilers implemented in c++) but hadn't seen that specifically. As far as Spirit, I've heard that it is great, if you can get it to work, but it's also pretty obtuse and hard to implement anything real world...